# createStore is @deprecated so im trying to replace with configurationStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

createStore is @deprecated so im trying to replace with configurationStore, i think the post data from my cluster is not showing because of that

````html
```

import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from "./reducers";

import App from './App'

const store = createStore(reducers, (compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))))
const root = ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);
````

```
And im trying to do it like this:
```

````html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import reducers from "./reducers";

import App from './App'

const store = configureStore(reducers, (compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))))
const root = ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));


root.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
);

```
````

Of Course it didn't work i'm trying to figure out how it could be

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would do

```js
const store = configureStore({ reducer: reducers })
```

The `thunk` middleware is active automatically. `compose` and `applyMiddleware` are not needed any more. So is `combineReducers`.

If you had

```js
const reducers = combineReducers({
  a: reducerA,
  b: reducerB
})
```

you could also just instead do

```js
const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: {
    a: reducerA,
    b: reducerB
  }
})
```

If you were still using `createStore`, that means that you were generally using an outdated style of Redux that is about 4x times the code of modern Redux.

Modern Redux does not use `switch..case` reducer, `ACTION_TYPE` constants, immutable reducer logic, hand-written action creators or `connect` & `mapStateToProps`. You might have been misled by an outdated tutorial.

I would highly recommend you to follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) which will leave you with knowledge of modern Redux and in the end much cleaner and easy to maintain code.

Comment: You were right i'm following an outdated tutorial now a change everything update Thank You so much